# Detailed proof of Theorem 2.1 in Papadimitrou book (Multitape TM to SingleTape TM)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, computability, turing-machines

I want to know if anybody knows a detailed proof of Theorem 2.1 of Papadimitrou's book Computational Complexity. The theorem states "Given any $k$-string Turing machine $M$ operating within time $O(f(n))$, we can construct a Turing Machine $M'$ operating within time $O(f(n)^2)$ and such that, for any input x, $M(x)=M'(x)$."

When asking for a detailed proof, I am asking for a complete description of $M'$.
For instance, in the proof of the book, there are statements (paragraph 4), like: "$M'$
must contain new states, each of which corresponds to a particular combination of a state of $M$ and of a $k$-tuple of symbols of $M$.", which are not detailed.

Do not misunderstand me, I do understand the proof, so I am not asking for an explanation. I want to know if anybody (maybe an old paper) make the effort to write a complete configuration for the new machine.

Comment: It does look like there is an explicit construction of this form in the accompanying code to this paper: https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/Publications/documents/ForsterEtAl_2019_VerifiedTMs.pdf (see section 7). I _think_ this is somewhere in here: https://github.com/uds-psl/coq-library-undecidability/blob/coq-8.14/theories/TM/Single/StepTM.v

Note that they use Coq to construct the machine; as good computer scientists will never do anything by hand that can be done by a computer.